# Proving that a uniformly convergent series times a function is also uniformly convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent over set E and the function $g(x)$ is bounded over E that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(x)f_n(x)$ is also uniformly convergent over the set E.

What I thought of: If $g(x)$ is bounded then  $ \exists \sup{g(x)} = M $ and $\exists \inf{g(x)} = m$. Then if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent then there exist $S(x)$ which is the sum of the series and $S(x)M$ $< \infty$ and also we have  $S(x)m$ $< \infty$. However, I don't know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not different between a function  series and a function sequence (since $g$ does not depend on $n$, you can place it in front of the series). So let $f_n$ be a function sequence that converges uniformly.

Let $f$ be the uniform limit of the sequence, then:

$$
(1):\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } n\geqslant N_\epsilon, \forall x\in A, ||f_n(x)-f(x)|| \leqslant \epsilon
$$

Then, $\forall x\in A, ||g(x)f_n(x)-g(x)f(x)||\leqslant  |g(x)|\times ||f_n(x)-f(x)|| \leqslant \sup |g| \times \epsilon$

Thus, applying (1) for $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{\sup |g|}$ is enough to see that the definition of uniform convergence holds for $(g\times f_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$|\sum_{n=M}^{N}g(x)f_n(x)| = |g(x)\sum_{n=M}^{N}f_n(x)|\le \sup_E|g|\cdot|\sum_{n=M}^{N}f_n(x)|.$$

Comment: It seems like you're going via uniformly cauchy - can it be done directly?

Comment: @B.Mehta I'm not sure what you mean my "directly". It can be done without appealing to "uniformly Cauchy", certainly.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your hint, from the limits on the sums, the argument here looks like you're using the fact that $\sum f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy to show that $\sum g f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy - especially since the lower limit is $M$ instead of $1$...

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes that's what I'm doing.